# Is there a button in iTunes to say "Stop after playing this song"?

Tags: itunes

Because I might just want to go to bed after this one song (but don't want to stop it midway – It's a classic).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### iTunes 11

Click on the Up Next button and press clear. It will stop after the current song regardless where you start the song from.

[image]

### iTunes 12

"Clear" is at the end of the Up Next list, rather than the top, so you'll have to take the extra step of scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: ⌥⌘U is a keyboard shortcut to open the Up Next pop-up. I don’t know of any built-in shortcut to Clear, but if you have Tab set to move keyboard focus between “All controls” (Control+F7 to toggle), then you can hit Clear after opening the pop-up by hitting Tab three times and then pressing Space.

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to work with podcast episodes, which carry on oblivious.

Comment: I do this all the time. I wish there were a way to make it stop after the current song _without_ clearing Up Next, though. (:

Comment: If you want to be able to clear the Up Next queue with a single keyboard shortcut, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/101049/21473).

Answer (score 5):

There's no command as such, but you can stop iTunes from playing after completing the current song by using the column browser to switch to any album other than the one of the current song. When the current song is done, iTunes will stop playing.

Comment: Hmm the trick doesn't quite work for me. When you say "Switching to any album other than the current one", it just means to click the album, right?

Comment: I believe this only works if you're using the column browser.

Comment: @Nathan - correct, will modify my answer.

Comment: Huh. Didn't know about that!

Answer (score 4):

No there is no command in iTunes but with Applescript you can add fuctionality. For iTunes and Applescript see [Doug's Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) and they have [one to stop after the current track](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=thisisthelastsong).

Comment: Just a heads-up, you'll need Rosetta to run the compiled version of this that downloads (so it won't work on Lion). The solution is to open the download in AppleScript Editor and Save As. This will recompile it for Intel.

Comment: I was really looking for a native solution, but I guess this or Neil's answer are the closest one.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in option to do this, but there are several third party apps that are made for your situation.

### [Berceuse](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/berceuse-from-gugusoft/id412325836?mt=12) ($2)

This one that does exactly what you asked (and more).
Basically, it lets you set a number of tracks to play, amount of time, or entire playlist to play before performing a set action (shut down, sleep, pause, etc.).

If you're looking for a free version, there are two options that are timers only (set them to the length of your song to play just one more).

### [iTunes Sleep Timer](http://www.mywebsight.ws/mac/applescripts/) (free)

This is an AppleScript that lets you very simply launch it and enter a number of second to continue playing for.

### [iTunes Timer](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/music/itunestimer.html) (free)

This is a dashboard widget that lets you drag a slider to set the time to continue playing for.

Answer (score 1):

Put the song in a playlist and click the check box off. All the songs in the playlist will have to be clicked off as well.

Or easier still have the track as the only song in the play list.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the search term in iTunes to search such that only that song is found, it will stop playing after it's finished (unless you've set it to loop). Or you can create a playlist with just that song and it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make this work with podcast episodes. So I do this:

Right click on the episode and select 'Show in Finder'. 
Then in Finder right click again and select 'Open in Quicktime Player'

I admit it is a clumsy workaround but it does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a playlist with the one song and that's all it will play.

Answer (score -1):

Just download the VOX player (it's free and great). There is an option in settings "autoplay", you can turn it off if You want to.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This doesn't really answer the OP's question so be prepared for downvotes.  You can see [answer] for tips on answering questions here.