# Set a keyboard shortcut to clear all tracks from the Up Next queue in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, applescript

I am looking for a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to clear *all* the tracks from  Up Next queue of iTunes. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Using Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4

Comment: Are you looking for a keyboard shortcut to add selected tracks to Up Next, or to view the Up Next list? Viewing already has a shortcut - option+command+U.

Comment: I want a shortcut to clear all the tracks from the up next queue

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659626/use-itunes-up-next-function-with-an-api which  uses gui scripting for adding a track to up next.  But it was not useful for clearing the up next queue with applescript unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.  it uses `cliclick` from http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/ to simulate a mouse click at the location of the clear button. The script assuming that `cliclick` is in `/usr/local/bin`

This works for me on a 15 inch macbook pro retina running at 1440x900@2x

To use the script either use [the instructions by Matthieu Riegler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101109/34352) for a global shortcut or use it from the command line

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        click (first button of scroll area 1 of window "iTunes" whose description is "up next")
        delay 1
        set upNextButton to button 4 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        set pos to upNextButton's position

        --  160, 54  the number of pixels away the clear button is

        set clearX to (item 1 of pos) + 160
        set clearY to (item 2 of pos) + 54
        set cmd to "/usr/local/bin/cliclick -- " & {clearX, " ", clearY}
        do shell script cmd

    end tell
end tell
```

also a script for the mini player assumes that the up next list is closed

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set upNextButton to (first button of window "MiniPlayer" whose description is "show up next")
        click upNextButton
        delay 1

        set pos to upNextButton's position
        --  19, 48  the number of pixels away the clear button is 
        set clearX to (item 1 of pos) + 19
        set clearY to (item 2 of pos) + 45

        set cmd to "/usr/local/bin/cliclick -- " & {clearX, " ", clearY}
        do shell script cmd

        delay 0.1
        click upNextButton

    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This following script will work on OSX < 10.7.

```
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        click (first button of scroll area 1 of window "iTunes" whose description is "up next")
        delay 1
        click button "Clear" of UI element 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Just tried it : Very buggy. Sometimes the Up Next queue is button 4, sometimes it's button 2.

Comment: Can be fixed within a try block

Comment: Still doesn't work. ( 0SX 10.8.4 /w iTunes 11.0.5)

Comment: Works in ( 0SX 10.6.8 /w iTunes 11.0.5)

Comment: I found why it doesn't work : iTunes on OSX >= 10.7 uses a NSPopover for `Up next` which is not available on 10.6 and below.

Comment: Good work all - could someone edit the question to specify an iTunes and OS X version since there is a difference that affects the answer

Comment: Nice work but on 10.8.4 it fails with the error after the up next button is clicked: `System Events got an error: Can’t get table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "iTunes". Invalid index.`

Answer (score 1):

So here's a complete answer :

---

For iTunes 11 & OS X 10.6 (iTunes 11 requires at least 10.6.8) :

- Create a new Automator service
- Select Service Receives **no input** In **iTunes**
- Add a **Run AppleScript action**
- copy the [code given by adayzdone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101100/8823). (You may need to adapt "up next" following the language of you system. For example on my French OS X it's "suivant")
- Save the service.
- Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts
- In Services, add a keyboard shortcut to your new service

---

For OS X 10.7 and above:

For the **up next** menu iTunes 11 uses an [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is available in OS X v10.7 and later. Therefore the hierarchy of UI Elements is different from the case above.

On iTunes 11.0.5, there is a bug where the button opening the Popover has no children. Therefore it is NOT possible to access the content of the popover to click on the clear button using Applescript.

Comment: I figured out a way of clicking the clear button by simulating a mouse click see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101158/34352

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for iTunes 12.9 on macOS Mojave 10.14. My solution simply listens for a trigger keystroke when iTunes is active and then fires a sequence of other keystrokes that presses the “Clear” button using only the keyboard.

The instructions below set this up using the paid app [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), but you should be able to replicate this using any other app that can listen to a keystroke and then fire other keystrokes. [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com/), [Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/), or AppleScript could be used in alternative solutions.

In Keyboard Maestro, first, create a folder “iTunes-specific mapping” with this configuration:

> Available in these applications:
>
> - iTunes

Then add a macro called `Clear “Up Next”` and set a trigger hot key:

> Triggered by any of the following (when iTunes is at front):
>
> - This hot key:
>
>   - <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> is pressed
>
> Will execute the following actions:

Click “+” to add an action, search for the “Type a Keystroke” action, and add five copies of it to the list of actions. Configure them to type these keystrokes in order:

1. <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (Show Up Next)
2. <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> (An OS-wide shortcut that toggles how <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through controls. See “Full Keyboard Access” at the bottom of System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts for more details. If your normal setting is already “All controls”, you don’t need this step.)
3. <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (focus the Clear button)
4. <kbd>Space</kbd> (activate the Clear button)
5. <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> (toggle Full Keyboard Access back to what it was before step 2)

After setting this up, with Keyboard Maestro open in the background, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> within iTunes to clear the Up Next queue.

A limitation of this solution: if there are no tracks in the Up Next queue, this sequence of keystrokes will instead pause the current track.

If this sequence of keystrokes isn’t working for you, it may be because the iTunes interface changed, or because the OS has responded to F7 too slowly and changed the behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> only *after* <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed. You can fix the first problem by changing the sent keystrokes, and you can fix the second problem by adding Pause actions between the keystrokes.

Comment: I don’t have time to edit my answer now, but I improved this solution to be more robust, such that you can safely trigger the macro even if no tracks are in Up Next. The key is to use the “if the screen contains an image” feature of Keyboard Maestro. After opening the Up Next popup, assert that it is actually visible on-screen. Then use an If statement to see if the popup already says “No upcoming songs.”, and just send an Escape keypress to close the popup if so.