# How do I prevent iTunes from playing the next track in an album or playlist

Tags: macos, itunes

I have a gig in about 23 days and I'm using iTunes to play the clips for each speaker.  I'm wondering if there is a sure fire way to stop iTunes from going to the next track? I tried to do my own research, however I'm kind of stumped as to what I can do as no one seems to have an answer. I **don't want to use another program** to do this. Of course I'll need to reverse the process after I'm done with the 3 day gig.

Thanks all.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82411) and see if it helps. It's a bit old but might still be applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this works. It will be a bit hard to hear my screen reader. (Oh by the way I'm visually impaired) but I will have it turned way up in my ears through another sound card.  Oh fun. It's kind of odd I have to tab to that clear button though. Oh well. Thanks thanks for such a quick answer. To reiterate what that link said if you need to see it at a glance do the following

- start a track playing.
- hit *command option u* to get to the next up window
- tab to clear and either click it or hit space.

I hope this also helps someone.